# Xcode Frameworks

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I have being doing a project in xcode, it is creation of the kings drinking game for ios.  I am using uiimages and nsdictionary to create the game the game is working fine.  However I have to implement a framework I havent used before.  I was wondering if someone could fill me in on possible frameworks i could use.

I was hoping there was a framework that would help with the displaying the rules when a card is turned.

For example the rule would be a string that is displayed to the screen depending on what card is drawn.  I would like to be able to display it to the screen without the use of a pop up box or text field.

if anyone could let me know if there is a possible framework that would do this or a framework that would work well with a card game for ios I would appreciate it.

Thanking You

Comment: you want to show text on the screen? use a UILabel?

Comment: You can use the UIKit framework...